# How to test django API with asychronous requests

Tags: python, django, multithreading, multiprocessing, tastypie

I am developing an API using Django-TastyPie.

**What API do?**

It checks that if two or more requests are there on the server if yes it swap the data of both the requests and return a json response after 7 second delay.

What i need to do is send multiple asynchronous requests to the server to test this API. 
I am using Django-Unit Test along with Tasty-Pie to test this functionality.

**Problem**

Django develpment server is single threaded so it does not support asynchronous requests

**Solution tried:**

I have tried to solve this by using multiprocessing:

```
class MatchResourceTest(ResourceTestCase):

def setUp(self):
    super(MatchResourceTest, self).setUp()

    self.user=""
    self.user_list = []
    self.thread_list = []

   # Create and get user
    self.assertHttpCreated(self.api_client.post('/api/v2/user/', format='json', data={'username': '123456','device': 'abc'}))
    self.user_list.append( User.objects.get(username='123456') )

    # Create and get other_user
    self.assertHttpCreated(self.api_client.post('/api/v2/user/', format='json', data={'username': '456789','device': 'xyz'}))
    self.user_list.append( User.objects.get(username='456789') )

def get_credentials(self):
    return self.create_apikey(username=self.user.username, api_key=self.user.api_key.key)

def get_url(self):
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(self.list_url).read()
    self.assertHttpOK(resp)

def test_get_list_json(self):

    for user in self.user_list:
        self.user = user
        self.list_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/match/?name=hello'

        t = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.get_url)
        t.start()
        self.thread_list.append( t )

    for t in self.thread_list:
        t.join()
        print ContactCardShare.objects.all()
```

Please suggest me any solution to test this API by sending asychronous requests

or

any APP , Library or any this which allow django development server to handle multiple requests asychronously

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [django's development server is multi-threaded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---nothreading).

I'm not sure this test is formatted correctly though. The test `setUp` shouldn't include tests itself, it should be foolproof data insertion by creating entries. The `post` should have it's own test.

See the [tastypie docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html#example-usage) for an example test case.